# material design lite with ReactJS form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, reactjs, material-design-lite

I have a registration form in a ReactJS render() function. It has the standard password retype field and i would like to ensure that an error message is displayed if the password fields do not match when 'Submit' is clicked. There is also an extra check for an empty password field which seems redundant - if the field is required and empty you would expect it to be invalid. I suspect there is a clean way to do this in a manner consistent with Material Design Lite.

My current attempt is at https://jsfiddle.net/5oh0yu72/4/ with code below.

```
== external resources ==
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-with-addons.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.min.js
https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css
https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons
https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js

== HTML ==
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

== JS ==
var Register = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      password: "",
      passwordRetyped: ""
    }
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var registerForm = document.getElementById('register');
    var formElements = registerForm.elements
    var elementCount = formElements.length
    var i = 0;
    for(;i<elementCount;i++){
      var elem = formElements[i]
      if(elem.checkValidity == false){
        alert("a field is invalid")
        return false
      }
    }
    var passwordElem = document.getElementById('password');
    var passwordRetypedElem = document.getElementById('passwordRetyped');
    if(passwordRetypedElem.value != passwordElem.value) {
      alert("The passwords do not match");
      return false;
    }
    if(passwordRetypedElem.value == '') {
      alert("The passwords are empty")
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },

  handlePasswordChange: function(e) {
    return this.setState({password: e.target.value})
  },

  handlePasswordRetypedChange: function(e) {
    return this.setState({passwordRetyped: e.target.value})
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div >
      < form id="register" className = "register" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
        < div className = "content-grid mdl-grid" >
          < div className = "mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--text-center mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" >
            < input className = "mdl-textfield__input"
              id = "password"
              type = "password"
              pattern = "[A-Z,a-z,0-9\?@\$%&\*\-_=+!~\.,\/\\]*"
              value = {
                this.state.password
              }
              onChange = {
                this.handlePasswordChange
              }
            required /> 
            < label className = "mdl-textfield__label"
              htmlFor = "password" > password * 
            < /label> 
            < span className = "mdl-textfield__error" >                   Input can only contain letters, numbers, and some special characters! 
            < /span> 
          < /div>
          < div className = "mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--text-center mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" >
            < input className = "mdl-textfield__input"
    id = "passwordRetyped"
    type = "password"
    pattern = "[A-Z,a-z,0-9\?@\$%&\*\-_=+!~\.,\/\\]*"
    value = {
      this.state.passwordRetyped
    }
    onChange = {
      this.handlePasswordRetypedChange
    }
            required /> 
            < label className = "mdl-textfield__label"
    htmlFor = "passwordRetyped" > retype password * < /label>             < span className = "mdl-textfield__error" > Input can only contain letters, numbers, and some special characters! 
            < /span> 
          < /div>

          < div className = "mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col" > 
            < input className = "mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-textfield--full-width"
    type = "submit"
    value = "Register" / >
          < /div> 

          < div className = "mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col" > 
            <p className='mdl-typography--headline mdl-typography--text-center'> * indicates a required field</p>
          < /div> 

        < /div > 
      < /form > 
    < /div >;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < Register / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

It uses an alert() to flag mismatched passwords but I have seen some solutions use a nav element to hold error messages. Just looking for a good, consistent way to do it.

thanks!

Comment: I'm currently using the MDL toast feature in development, as described at http://getmdl.io/components/index.html .